# Can you pass information between two nested Group BY statements in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, group-by

I'm trying to find a way to pass data from a nested GROUP BY statement. Below are my two tables that I have created specifically for this example

```
    TABLE: GROCERIES                                      TABLE: MAP

NAME     FRUIT    WEIGHT                              NAME      LOCATION
-----    -----    ------                              -----     --------
AMY      APPLE    76                                  Amy       Mondale, CA
BOB      APPLE    90                                  Bob       Oakmont, CA
AMY      APPLE    86                                  Chuck     Phoenix, AZ
CHUCK    APPLE    80                                  Derrick   Taos, NM
CHUCK    APPLE    86
AMY      ORANGE   125
BOB      ORANGE   135
CHUCK    ORANGE   115
DERRICK  ORANGE   136
DERRICK  ORANGE   114
BOB      ORANGE   150
DERRICK  ORANGE   143
BOB      BANANA   119
BOB      BANANA   118
CHUCK    BANANA   123
CHUCK    BANANA   110
CHUCK    BANANA   130
AMY      BANANA   100
```

My goal was to find the average weight of each fruit that each person has, and then calculate who has the highest average among each fruit. Below is ***WORKING*** code that demonstrates this

```
SELECT FRUIT, MAX(avg_weight) as WEIGHT
FROM (SELECT NAME, FRUIT, ROUND(AVG(WEIGHT)) AS avg_weight
      FROM GROCERIES GROUP BY NAME, FRUIT) tmp
GROUP BY FRUIT
```

```
FRUIT         WEIGHT
--------- ----------
Orange           143 
Apple             90 
Banana           121
```

But the problem is that I do not know how to "pass" the Name column to the front so that it can be connected to the Map Table, and thus, print out the location of each person who received the highest amount.

**What I Want To Happen**

```
FRUIT         WEIGHT       NAME       LOCATION
--------- ----------       -------    -----------
Orange           143       Bob        Oakmont, CA
Apple             90       Bob        Oakmont, CA
Banana           121       Chuck      Phoenix, AZ
```

If I call Name in the outer SELECT statement, then I would also have to GROUP BY that same column (so they match) and it would skew my results

```
SELECT NAME, FRUIT, MAX(avg_weight) as WEIGHT
FROM (SELECT NAME, FRUIT, ROUND(AVG(WEIGHT)) AS avg_weight
FROM GROCERIES GROUP BY NAME, FRUIT)
tmp GROUP BY NAME, FRUIT


NAME     FRUIT         WEIGHT
-------- --------- ----------
Amy      Apple             81 
Chuck    Orange           115 
Amy      Orange           125 
Derrick  Orange           131 
Bob      Banana           119 
Chuck    Banana           121 
Bob      Apple             90 
Chuck    Apple             83 
Bob      Orange           143 
Amy      Banana           100 

10 rows selected
```

Comment: You simply need to join the result of your "working code" back to `GROCERIES` (on fruit name and weight) and then to `MAP`.

Comment: @mustaccio Are you talking about INNER JOIN? I couldn't get 'name' to connect since it wasn't called in the outer Group By statement

Comment: @mustaccio: This would work with the maximum weight, but the average weight is not stored in any column you could join to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably the most straightforward way to accomplish what you want. Be aware that in the event of ties it would return all people/locations in the tie for first place.

```
WITH AVG_PER_FRUIT_PER_PERSON AS (
    SELECT NAME, FRUIT, ROUND(AVG(WEIGHT)) AS avg_weight
    FROM GROCERIES
    GROUP BY NAME, FRUIT
), MAX_APFPP_PER_FRUIT AS (
    SELECT FRUIT, MAX(avg_weight) AS max_weight
    FROM AVG_PER_FRUIT_PER_PERSON
    GROUP BY FRUIT
)
SELECT a.FRUIT, a.avg_weight AS WEIGHT, a.NAME, MAP.LOCATION
FROM
    MAX_APFPP_PER_FRUIT m INNER JOIN
    AVG_PER_FRUIT_PER_PERSON a
        ON a.avg_weight = m.max_weight AND a.FRUIT = m.FRUIT INNER JOIN
    MAP
        ON MAP.Name = a.Name;
```

Using analytic functions you might instead prefer:

```
WITH AVG_PER_FRUIT_PER_PERSON AS (
    SELECT NAME, FRUIT, ROUND(AVG(WEIGHT)) AS avg_weight
    FROM GROCERIES
    GROUP BY NAME, FRUIT
), RANKED_APFPP_PER_FRUIT AS (
    SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY FRUIT ORDER BY avg_weight DESC) as DR
    FROM AVG_PER_FRUIT_PER_PERSON
)
SELECT r.FRUIT, r.avg_weight AS WEIGHT, r.NAME, MAP.LOCATION
FROM RANKED_APFPP_PER_FRUIT r INNER JOIN MAP ON MAP.NAME = r.NAME
WHERE DR = 1;
```

Comment: I'm getting an error with your code. Error at Command Line:13 Column:37. Error report: SQL Error: ORA-00904: "MPF"."AVG_WEIGHT": invalid identifier 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: @Noah, I had really screwed up the aliases and cte names but I think I got it fixed.

Comment: Where does the Map table connect to?

Comment: Nevermind my last comment. There was just a mixup with the Table name. It works perfectly!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Noah, I had just accidentally called the table `LOCATION` rather than `MAP`.

Comment: Hey I know it's been a few days, but I have a question. Is it possible to turn that into an SQL procedure? I'm trying to figure out how to accomplish that

Comment: @Noah, Does it have arguments? Just add `create procedure <name> as begin` at the top and `end<line break>go` at the bottom.

Comment: @Noah, I take that back. You're using Oracle not SQL Server.

Comment: Yeah I'm using Oracle. I just can't figure out how to include the WITH clause

Comment: @Noah, Does this apply? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26890512/oracle-using-ctes-common-table-expressions-with-pl-sql In particular this sentence: *Just google "oracle return ref cursor to caller" to get a whole lot of good material.* It's funny that I personally know the guy who wrote that :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve the same result.

```
SELECT T1.NAME, T1.FRUIT,AVG_WEIGHT, 
(SELECT T2.LOCATION FROM TST1_MAP T2 WHERE UPPER(T2.NAME)=T1.NAME) LOCATION
FROM (SELECT NAME, FRUIT,AVG(WEIGHT) AVG_WEIGHT,
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY  FRUIT
ORDER BY AVG(WEIGHT) DESC ) AS RANK1
FROM TST1_GROCERIES 
GROUP BY NAME,FRUIT) T1
WHERE RANK1 = 1;
```

PS: for my database schema I added TST1_ infront of the table name.

Answer (score 0):

Following query is working as you as you want it to happen. I tried to explain the query by adding comments in the query starting with **// and ending at **. Please remove these before you run the query.

```
SELECT 
AvgTable.NAME,
maxAvgTable.FRUIT,
maxAvgTable.WEIGHT,
MAP.location
FROM


**// Max Average Table Below (This holds max avg values)**

(SELECT 
    FRUIT, MAX(avg_weight) AS WEIGHT
FROM
    (SELECT 
    NAME, FRUIT, ROUND(AVG(WEIGHT)) AS avg_weight
FROM
GROCERIES
GROUP BY NAME , FRUIT) AS tmp
GROUP BY fruit) AS maxAvgTable

**// Left joined with AvgTable to get the 'Names'**

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT 
    NAME, FRUIT, ROUND(AVG(WEIGHT)) AS avg_weight
FROM
    GROCERIES
GROUP BY NAME , FRUIT) AS AvgTable ON maxAvgTable.WEIGHT = AvgTable.avg_weight
    AND maxAvgTable.FRUIT = AvgTable.FRUIT


**// Left joined with map table to get the location**

LEFT JOIN
map ON AvgTable.name = map.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `keep`, that is the easiest way in Oracle:

```
SELECT FRUIT, MAX(avg_weight) as WEIGHT,
       MAX(NAME) OVER (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY avg_weight DESC) as NameWithHighestAverage
FROM (SELECT NAME, FRUIT, ROUND(AVG(WEIGHT)) AS avg_weight
      FROM GROCERIES
      GROUP BY NAME, FRUIT
     ) tmp
GROUP BY FRUIT;
```